# git stash on windows failing with unable to create lock but creates the stash index ok

Tags: git

everytime i try to do a

```
$ git stash
fatal: Unable to create '/c/src/source_home/web/.git/.git-stash.1136-index.lock': No such   file or directory
Cannot save the current worktree state
```

if i go to the .git directory i see **.git-stash.1136-index**, so I assuming that means the permissions are ok?

the OS is Win Server 2003

git checkout, pull, push , status all work.

I have checked the permissions for the folder and they are ok, but I assume that since the index is being created that should not be an issue

this is what git status shows

```
$ git status
# On branch rest_api_v1
# Your branch is ahead of 'hive/rest_api_v1' by 1 commit.
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   appserver/site/bin/ance.dll
#       modified:   appserver/site/bin/ance.pdb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: updated to include git status

Comment: Try deleting `/c/src/source_home/web/.git/.git-stash.1136-index.lock` manually (keep a backup, just in case) and then run `git stash` again.

Comment: jubobs, there is no .git-stash.1136-index.lock. That appears to be the problem. It creates a .git-stash.1136-index but no .git-stash.1136-index.lock

Comment: Sorry, I meant delete `.git-stash.1136-index` and try `git stash` again.

Comment: when i delete it, and do a git stash it just creates a new index fails creating the lock for the new index just created

Answer (score 0):

"[`git stash`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/70550a224263099c76276eaa57ac9d0b0c724a99/Documentation/git-stash.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash))</sup> sometimes was silent even when it failed due to unwritable index file, which has been corrected with Git 2.43.2 (Q1 2024), [rc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad1a6695454c6fd922617b03ebb5678841a17db5).

If, in your case, the index was locked, git stash should now at least tell you so.

```
error: could not write index
```

See [commit d2058cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2058cb2f00ae4c174b44193b039790dc8015c40) (06 Feb 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 70550a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70550a224263099c76276eaa57ac9d0b0c724a99), 12 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/stash`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2058cb2f00ae4c174b44193b039790dc8015c40): report failure to write to index
>
> <sup>Reported-by: moti sd</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> The git-stash(1) command needs to write to the index for many of its operations.
> When the index is locked by a concurrent writer it will thus fail to operate, which is expected.
> What is not expected though is that we do not print any error message at all in this case.
> The user can thus easily miss the fact that the command didn't do what they expected it to do and would be left wondering why that is.
>
> Fix this bug and report failures to write to the index.
> Add tests for the subcommands which hit the respective code paths.
>
> While at it, unify error messages when writing to the index fails.
> The chosen error message is already used in "[`builtin/stash.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d2058cb2f00ae4c174b44193b039790dc8015c40/builtin/stash.c)".